# Azure Stream Analytics and Power BI

Tags: azure, powerbi, azure-stream-analytics

I have an Azure Stream Analytics job outputting to PowerBI - outputs are present and the data set is present in PowerBI - however, the graph is not live as I have to manually refresh the page to receive the updated data.

How do I go about having a live feed of data?

Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After pinning the graph to a dashboard it should refresh in real time.  There are some limitations about the throughput that a PowerBI dashboard can handle and sending a large volume of events may result in latency in the view.  Details in the Limitations and Best Practices topic here: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/stream-analytics-power-bi-dashboard/

Comment: @RaymondDillon, i had the similar challenge, let me know how you got refreshing work automatically. Kindly explain!

Comment: Hi @IlyasF - I created my reports from my streaming data through Power BI. I then created a dashboard (name it whatever you like). On the report, there should be a pin icon at the top right of each report item - click on it to add to the dashboard and it should be live :)